# Can someone identify a resistor with only markings on it see TP?

Tags: resistors, identification, surface-mount

I am trying to repair circuit boards that fried on my hydraulic anchors (Power Poles) on my boat.  Both have the same resistor fried. I have found the same one elsewhere on the board, see pic.  I tested on my multimeter and get .9 ohm.  The only marking on it is TP.  Anyone know where I can get these?[image: Photo of resistor in question]

Comment: What makes you think it's fried?

Comment: Please don't post two almost duplicate questions. You can edit questions to add something. As this newer queation better reflects what you are asking, I think you can just delete your previous question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm taking a wild stab in the dark, [but could it be a fuse?](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_468_datasheet.pdf.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Been like 20 years since I last assembled a board.  Forgot about those types of fuses going in Resistor slots.  Ordered $10 with shipping.  Manufacturer would only sell complete boards at $240 each.

Comment: I thought of this and dismissed it based on the R designator... I wonder why they called it R1 and not F1?

Comment: @Hearth perhaps so that they could sell replacement boards ... lol

Comment: @JeffereyBanko Now if these are fuses, you are looking at symptoms, not the root of the problem. Replacing them won't fix the reason they blew. Same deal as when a fuse blows in your house, really. You have to find the part causing it.